# LinkedIn API: Error showing while listing UGC posts

Tags: linkedin-api

#linkedIn
My client wants me to fetch all the feeds from his LinkedIn organization. I tried using their marketing developer platform and got the permissions. But when I tried to fetch the feeds using urn id and I got responses like

Request: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts/urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A1234

Response :

```
{
    "message": "com.linkedin.content.common.ResponseException: ",
    "status": 404
}
```

I am a little bit confused about this response. Can someone help me in sorting this out?

Comment: Have you set the access token in the request header?

Comment: Yes..I have set the bearer token in the request header.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your {URN} is incorrect. the correct format is urn:li:organization:{id}